# Adding a file to Google Drive through Google Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In a standalone Google Script, I have made a created a Google Sheet using its API, by using it's `SpreadsheetApp.create()` function, and filled the spreadsheet with data.

I have to add this file to Google Drive, but I have no idea how. I'm assuming that the create() method doesn't add it to drive automatically. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `SpreadsheetApp.create()` it creates a new spreadsheet that is natively (and obviously) in your Drive. There is no need to add it to your drive and it actually doesn't make any sense.
You can eventually check that easily with this small code :

```
function testCreate(){
  var newSs = SpreadsheetApp.create("new test spreadsheet");
  Browser.msgBox("file in drive is "+DriveApp.getFileById(newSs.getId()).getName());
}
```

note : run this from a spreadsheet (any spreadsheet) because it uses the `Browser.msgBox(`) method that only works in spreadsheets.

Comment: you have been an angel sent down from heaven to help me understand everything. Thanks!!

Comment: just going on a long shot, but do you have any way to contact you outside of this? My code is pretty much complete but now I just have to test it (and I've never written in Google Scripts before so I'm sure there are dumb mistakes everywhere). I'm kind of restricted for time to complete this and it would be really helpful. If you can't, I completely understand and thank you for the tremendous amount of help you've been!

Comment: Time is one of the rarest things in our lives... I'm afraid I have to decline your proposal but if something isn't working this community is generally a great help. Good luck and thanks for the kind words.

Comment: Thanks I completely understand, and I'm hoping for the best of luck testing this code!

Comment: I'm only getting one error in which I get "The API method 'getUi' is only available in the new version of Google Sheets", and I have no idea how to fix that

Comment: you are probably working on an old version of spreadsheets... do you see a small green sign (v) in the right bottom of the sheet ? Or do you have a menu item called "Add-ons" ?

Comment: Yeah I see a green check mark assuring I'm working in the new version. But just a question, this whole time I've been working in a standalone script (I just clicked "blank project" and started coding), and apparently to use getUi(), I must make it a bounded script to Sheets. I'm assuming I make this as an add-on for Google Sheets (custom function doesn't sound right for something that will create a spreadsheet for you and then e-mail it to you as a PDF). So I'll just copy and paste this onto the new file? I'm finding this harder than the actual coding

Comment: Does your script use HTML to create the UI ? Have you considered deploying a webapp ?

Comment: I think I found the problem, and it's that I was working in a standalone script, which are not able to call the getUi() methods, so I've just copied and pasted everything to the add-on thing. And my script doesnn't use HTML, just calls ui.prompt() to prompt the user. And I don't really have enough time to deploy a webapp (as I think [don't take my word] would require like coding the design and everything).